# defining path of a file in linux server while using .net core

Tags: c#, linux, asp.net-core, .net-core

Consider I've deployed my C# application in a Linux server, here is a path of my deployed application:

```
/var/www/app
```

In my application, I want to address to an external file which is in this path:

```
/etc/letsencrypt/certificate/cert.pfx
```

Can I just use this address the way it is, I mean is it correct to define it something like this:

```
options.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 443,
                        listenOptions => { listenOptions.UseHttps("/etc/letsencrypt/certificate/cert.pfx"); })
```

I'm concerned because this is my first time I want to deploy on Linux server and I know paths are different from what I see in the windows.

Comment: typically paths stay the same depending on the distro, you don't have to worry about Windows stuff like "C:\myfiles" vs "D:\myfiles". If "letsencrypt" installs to that path by default, then it should be consistent across linux distros.

Comment: tnx, I deployed my app without any problem